# How do I change the number of AF points on Canon 7D Mark ii?

Tags: canon, autofocus, canon-7d

When I use A/I servo for moving subjects, I only see 5 Auto Focus points. I would like to expand this however I cannot find where to do this. I would like to try 9 or 15.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Frustrated!!

Comment: Thank you for that information, however it did not change anything. I use * as my back button for a/I servo. The camera is set up to be in "one shot" as default using af-on for focus. When I push * It then becomes AI servo however I still cannot figure out how to increase AF points when I switch to AI Servo.

Answer (score 2):

From the *[EOS 7D MArk II AF Setting Guidebook](https://media.canon-asia.com/shared/live/products/EN/K289AFGuideBook_web.pdf)*:

[image: Page 20]
[image: Page 21]

Much of the same information, some of it in greater detail, can be found on pages 85-98 of the [*EOS 7D Mark II Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300016615/01/eos7d-mk2-im-en.pdf) (for the revised version of the manual released with firmware version 1.1.0 -  the page numbers may be slightly different from earlier versions of the manual).

Keep in mind that you can only select most of these options when shooting in **P**, **Tv**, **Av**, and **M** exposure modes. If you're shooting in the fully auto **Scene Intelligent Auto Mode** (**A+** on your mode dial) the camera makes those decision for you.

Also keep in mind that all of the AF points will not be available with all lenses. Only lenses with wider maximum apertures can use all of the capabilities of all of the AF points. As you select lenses with narrower maximum apertures you give up some of those capabilities. The narrower the lens, the more restricted your options are. That's all covered in pages 99-107 of the [*Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300016615/01/eos7d-mk2-im-en.pdf).

Finally, depending on how some of the other many configurable options for your camera's AF are selected, the AF area may be preserved differently in different AF modes. For instance, say you are shooting in *One Shot* AF mode and have *AF Point Expansion (8 surrounding points)* selected for the AF area. When you switch to *AI Servo AF* mode the camera will remember that the last time you were in *AI Servo AF* mode you had *Single Point AF* selected for the AF area and will use that. To switch to *AF Point Expansion (8 surrounding points)* for the AF area you need to make that selection while in *AI Servo AF* mode. If you have separate settings enabled for vertical/portrait and horizontal/landscape orientations, you also need to have the camera in whichever orientation you wish to affect when you change AF mode and AF area selection.